# Передать $_SESSION['logged'] из субдомена в домен

Tags: php, сессия

нужна помощь .
Не получается передать `$_SESSION['logged']` из субдомена
и получить его `<? if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user']) ) : ?>` в домене.
Возможно ли передать `$_SESSION['logged']` из субдомена в домен ?
Пробовал делать так:
   `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/tmp', 'domain.com'); 
 session_start();`

Comment: Посмотрите тут:  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-cookie-params.php.  Чтобы сделать cookies видимыми для всех поддоменов, перед именем домена нужно поставить точку, например '.php.net'. Попробуйте: session_set_cookie_params(600, "/", ".site.com", false, false);

Comment: @МаксМаксимус - Спасибо за совет , но мне нужно сделать их видимыми в домене . То есть передать `$_SESSION['logged']`  из суб.домен.com > домен.com. Я пытаюсь разделить аккаунты пользователей и регистрацию от домена.com и держать их всех в суб.домен.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** суб.домен.сом > Файле db.php***

```
$rootDomain = '.Domain.com';
session_name('sess');
session_set_cookie_params($currentCookieParams["lifetime"].'600', 
$currentCookieParams["path"].'/', $rootDomain ,$currentCookieParams["secure"].false, 
$currentCookieParams["httponly"].false);
session_start();
ob_start();
```

*** домен.сом > Файле index.php***

```
header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8");
session_name('mysessionname');
session_start();
ob_start();
```

*После регистрации делаю редирект из `суб.домен.сом > домен.сом` файлом `htaccess`*

*Метод конечно не идеальный но это то что на данный момент у меня получилось ,может кому пригодится.*